# Why can't DropDownListFor use a public field?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

```
Public List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem(){ "Values initialized here"}
}
```

The above list does not play nice when used in a `DropDownListFor` but if I instead made list a property and returned the list in its getter... `DropDownListFor` accepts it.

Why?

Comment: Apart from the typo's in your code, what problem are you having? - it will work fine

Comment: @StephenMuecke have you run it? I wrote this on my cell phone. I'll be able to get to my PC tomorrow

Comment: Works fine for me :) You need to show the view code